# how can I create multi language site with Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

hi my friends I have a question
how can I create multi language site with Nuxt?
my site is ssr and I don't want use any package beacuse client wants to me handle this without package

Comment: Hi. You should not ask for tutorial/guides in SO. Also, there is the i18n package with Nuxt but since you told that you don't want to use any package, I don't know what to say. https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/ You can create your own solution with some vanilla code I guess.

Comment: tanx i check it
but they want i do it witout package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you don't want to use the [i18n package](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/) but as told before: You can create your own solution with some vanilla code I guess.
IMO, you will lose quite some time doing this. I'd prefer to use a package who does that well rather than trying to achieve it myself because I'd probably bump into un-expected edge cases.

You can always get inspiration from the i18n module source code itself but then, why not use it directly. Using a battle tested package in the JS world is not a bad idea. Especially if it's mantained well (by Pooia).

Reminds me of this one: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png

Comment: you say right it is very better that i handle this by i81 but it is not my private project!
they wants to me that i handle this without package
i trying say to theme wat is best way
anyway thanks for your help my friendssss

Comment: Strange that you have that kind of limitation from a client tbh @faezeh

Comment: beacuse i am trainee and i am in Learning
i should do it without package

Comment: @faezeh this is not a valid point. Because you are a trainee, you should build your computer from bare metal? Create JavaScript (language itself) from binary? Build your own keyboard, monitor and HTTP protocol? Non-sense. We are developers, we do have tools. Why won't we use the tools that are available to craft things? For somebody new in the industry, reinventing the wheel on a whole i18n system is not something that is anyhow useful nor interesting skill-wise. By extrapolation, your colleagues do not use Vue, nor Nuxt, nor Babel, nor Webpack? Or did they built their own versions on weekend?

Comment: Have to disagree wıth @kissu . Why was Vue written when there already was some other framework? Does Vue itself remind of xkcd standards or not? Why should someone learn how electricity works, instead of just plugging plugs into outlets at home?